# Determine the number of possible for the following table

Tags: combinatorics

If we put numbers  1 and -1 in the squares such that the sum of any row is zero. Also the sum of any column is zero. Now determine the number of possible for the table.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both $+1$ and $-1$ occur twice in each row and column. There are $\binom42=6$ different arrangements for the first row. Without loss of generality, we can assume that the first row is $+1,+1,-1,-1$ and multiply the result by $6$ in the end. Then there's one more $+1$ in the first column. Without loss of generality, we can assume it's in the second row and multiply the result by $3$ in the end. Now we've fixed:

```
+ + - -
+
-
-
```

Now placing another $+1$ in the second row and column determines the remaining entries, whereas placing a $-1$ there leaves two choices for the row in which to place the remaining $+1$ in the second column and two choices for the column in which to place the remaining $+1$ in the second row. Thus the total number of possibilities is $6\cdot3\cdot(1+2\cdot2)=90$, and indeed searching OEIS for $2,90$ yields [OEIS sequence A058527](https://oeis.org/A058527), the "number of $2n\times2n$ $0$–$1$ matrices with $n$ ones in each row and each column".

Comment: is there a nice proof for the general case of $2n \times 2n$ matrices in the special case where the row and column sums are zero?

Comment: @Vincent: A proof of what? Do you mean a closed form? I doubt that one is known; usually such formulas are noted in the OEIS entries; the OEIS entry in this case says that the terms were computed using dynamic programming.

Comment: I was hoping for a closed form, but it looks like there isn't any. However, is there an explanation on how the OEIS sequence is calculated? I have been taking a look at some of the papers linked and so far have not been able to find an exact result for the calculation of sequence.

Comment: @Vincent: Did you follow the McKay link in the OEIS entry? It leads to [some Maple code](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/Bvals.maple). If you have further questions, you could contact one of the people who supplied the terms for the entry; their email addresses are listed.

Comment: thank you, I'll take a look at that in detail and contact those people who supplied the terms.